# Indeed individual job links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hyperlink

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but am trying to pull some jobs from indeed, and to get the url for the page from the title, just so I can also get the description from the new page.
It used to work fine but recently am having this error code come up:

*link = jobs.find("a", class_="jobtitle")["href"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable*

Anyway, here is the code.

```
    results = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "result"})

    for jobs in soup.find_all(class_="result"):

        **link = jobs.find("a", class_="jobtitle")["href"]
        if "http" not in link:
            link = "http://uk.indeed.com" + link
        print("Link:", link)**

        page = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
        try:
            job_description = soup.find(
                "div", id="jobDescriptionText"
            ).decode_contents(formatter="html")
        except Exception as e:
            job_description = None
        print("job_description:", job_description)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

With this, you may need to use `get` to pull the href from the tag:

```
link = jobs.find("a", class_="jobtitle").get("href")
```